# Does the Galaxy S2 have two mics?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, microphone

I need a straightforward answer, does the Samsung Galaxy S2 have two microphones? I tried to Google it but was not too successful. Two mics are essential for my upcoming project. Thank you for all your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy S2 does have dual microphones.

However, if using Gingerbread (2.3), the device only records mono audio.

Using Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) though, the device can record stereo audio at about 130 Kbps with a sampling rate of 48KHz.

Source: [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_ii_ics_vs_gingerbread-review-737p3.php)

Answer (score 2):

It does have a dedicated 2nd microphone for active noise cancellation according to [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9100_galaxy_s_ii-3621.php).